# GCP App Engine whatsapp-web.js not generating QR code

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a node.js app that uses whatsapp-web.js, I'm using Cloud Shell Editor to execute my app, when I see it in Web Preview everything it's okay, but when I execute: `gcloud app deploy` and I see my url, the QR code is not generated.

I executed: `gcloud app logs tail -s default`, and I found this error in console:

```
/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:230
error: new Errors_js_1.ProtocolError(),
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
```

Node version: 18.12.1

This is my code

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require("axios");
var cors = require('cors')

const config = require("./config.json");
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require("whatsapp-web.js");

process.title = "whatsapp-node-api";
global.client = new Client({
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth({clientId: "my-client", dataPath: "/tmp"}),
  puppeteer: {
      headless: true,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox','--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    },
});

global.authed = false;

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

const port = process.env.PORT || config.port;

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

client.on("qr", (qr) => {
  console.log("qr");
  process.last_qr = qr;
});

client.on("authenticated", () => {
  console.log("AUTH!");
  authed = true;
  process.last_qr = undefined;
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Client is ready!");
});

client.on("disconnected", () => {
  console.log("disconnected");
});
client.initialize();

const chatRoute = require("./components/chatting");
const authRoute = require("./components/auth");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.method + " : " + req.path);
  next();
});
app.use("/chat", chatRoute);
app.use("/auth", authRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server Running Live on Port : " + port);
});
```

My app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs18
env: standard
instance_class: F4_1G
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.initialize();
```

Source: https://wwebjs.dev/guide/#qr-code-generation

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass this option to puppeteer as well:

`args: ['--no-sandbox','--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']`

**Explanation**:

By default, **Puppeteer** uses shared memory within `/dev/shm` shared memory space, and, within containers they are defaulted to 64MB. This is typically too small for Chrome and will cause Chrome to crash when rendering medium or large pages. To fix, either run the container with `docker run --shm-size=1gb` to increase the size of `/dev/shm`, but since you are using **App Engine** I bet you won't be able to.

But, here is the good news...Since Chrome 65, the usage of shared memory is no longer necessary. Instead, launch the browser with the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flag as per up above in `args` parameters.

This will write shared memory files into `/tmp` instead of `/dev/shm`. See crbug.com/736452 for more details.